# How to mock a controller that implements an interface

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, moq

So I'm trying to test the case where this method will return the "ManagerEventsIndex":

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (this.CurrentUser != null)
        {
            if (this.CurrentUser.Role.Name == AvailableRoles.GameManager)
            {
                var model = new GameManagerEventsIndexModel();
                model.NumLocationsOfCurrentUser = this._customerLocationDataProvider.GetAllForUserId(CurrentUser.Id)
                                                                                    .Where(x => x.Active == true)
                                                                                    .Count();
                return View("ManagerEventsIndex", model);
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
        else
            return View("PublicIndex");
    }
```

But this controller implements another controller ApplicationController like so: EventsController : ApplicationController, and it's the CurrentUser object in the Application controller that I need to mock in order to test this... here's my test method so far. Thanks.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void AssertGameManagerRoleReturnsGameManagerIndex()
    {
        // Arrange
        //eventsController = new EventsController(eventDataProvider.Object, playerEventDataProvider.Object, userDataProvider.Object,
                                                tokenAuthent.Object, dataContext.Object, customerLocationDataProvider.Object);

        var user = new Mock<User>();
        var role = new Mock<Role>();
        role.SetupSet(x => x.Name = "Ted");
        user.SetupSet(x => x.Role = role.Object);

        //?? var appController = new Mock<ApplicationController>();
        //?? appController.SetupSet(x => x.User = user);

        // var mController = new Mock<EventsController>();

        // Act
        var result = (ViewResult) eventsController.Index();

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual("ManagerEventsIndex", result.ViewName);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue here is that you have too much functionality built into the instance of your controller class, and this is making it harder to test.

When you test you want to make sure that all of the bits which are not part of the System Under Test (SUT) are manipulable. This allows you to tweek all of the other bits to produce scenarios.

If user is something you want to tweek independently from the controller you have two options:

- make the object you want to tweek externally accessible (in this case make User public)
- Decouple your user from the actual implementation and pass a IUserService or similar into the class at construction time.

These will give you access to be able to play with the object in your tests. Normally when you come across issues like this where things are a bit hard to test its a good indicator that you haven't modularised you SUT properly.

Comment: hmm so there's no way to make a mock controller and at the same time specify the mock interface it should implement?

Comment: @mapleafman I don't think moq supports anything like that. You can either mock a whole interface or a whole instance (not join the two together). i suppose my point is that if you feel like you are having to do crazy things in your tests to produce a scenario its normally a code smell suggesting that perhaps you haven't broken the actual SUT down in the right way

Comment: thanks I appreciate it, and I agree, just working on this with someone else and it's mostly their design, just was trying to see if there was something that could be done, thanks